# Why it didn't print out the argument?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I try to do this program that will encrypt a name with a chosen offset number. So the user will need to enter their name (less than 8 characters) and 1 offset number from 0-9. Supposedly, the output for this program is the encrypted name after the offset of the chosen offset number. It already encrypts the name, but didn't print it out.

```
la  $t0,name
la  $t1,encryptedname
    
encrypt :
    lb  $t2,0($t0)
    add $t3,$s0,$t2
    sb  $t3,0($t1)
    addi    $t0,$t0,1
    addi    $t1,$t1,1
    bne $t2,$zero,encrypt

jal PrintEncryptedName

PrintEncryptedName:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, encryptednamemsg
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,encryptedname
    move $a0, $s1
    syscall
    jr $ra
```

Comment: There could be all sorts of reasons. Maybe the code isn't actually executed. Maybe the string starts with a NUL character (value 0). Maybe the string only contains whitespace / non-printable characters. Use the debugging features of MARS to find out.

Comment: Btw, what's the point of the `move $a0, $s1` directly following `la $a0,encryptedname` ?